# Append contents of an array to a multidimensional array Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, google-cloud-firestore

Every time I fetch data from Firestore I want to append it to the last array in "PostsArray"

```
var postsArray = [[Posts]]()

func fetchData () {
  let firestoreRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Posts")
  firestoreRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
      if error != nil {
        print (error!.localizedDescription)
      } else {
        guard let snapshot = snapshot else {return}
        for document in snapshot.documents {
            let data = document.data()
            let number = data["Number"] as? Int ?? 0
            let newPost = Post(num: number)

            self.postsArray.last.append(newPost) 
   }
  }
 }
```

What I need help with is the last line: **self.postsArray.last.append(newPost)**.

I want to append **newPost** to the last array of **postsArray**. However, it returns an error: **Value of type '(([Post]) throws -> Bool) throws -> [Post]?' has no member 'append'**. What does it mean and how do i fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Sh_Khan has fixed the main problem, but doesn't allow for an empty `posts` array.  You will need to test for an empty outer array, and then cope with an empty inner array

```
if postsArray.isEmpty {
   postsArray.append([newPost]) //no inner array at all
} else {
   postsArray[postsArray.index(before: postsArray.endIndex)].append(newPost) //allows for an empty inner array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a small mistake in code. You should write like this:

```
self.postsArray.last?.append(newPost)
```

Comment: This won't work `last` will return an immutable variable that has no `append`